# Why is the bind method not working in python kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I am at a complete loss, why is the `on_packet` method not being called in either of the classes.  I have plenty of other bindings in my app but for some reason these do not seem to work??

```py
from kivy.uix.checkbox import CheckBox
from kivy.uix.switch import Switch
from kivy.app import runTouchApp
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout


class FXSwitch(Switch):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.bind(on_active=self.on_packet)

    def on_active(self, *args):
        print('on_active')

    def on_packet(self, *args):
        print('on_packet')
        print(args)


class FXCheckBox(CheckBox):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.bind(on_state=self.on_packet)

    def on_state(self, *args):
        print('on_state')

    def on_packet(self, *args):
        print('on_packet')
        print(args)


grid = GridLayout(cols=1)
sw = FXSwitch()
sw.bind(on_active=sw.on_packet)

grid.add_widget(sw)
grid.add_widget(FXSwitch())
grid.add_widget(FXCheckBox())
runTouchApp(grid)
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out instead of binding `on_state` and `on_active` I needed to bind to `active`.  Revised code below:

```py
from kivy.uix.checkbox import CheckBox
from kivy.uix.switch import Switch
from kivy.app import runTouchApp
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout


class FXSwitch(Switch):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.bind(active=self.on_packet)

    def on_active(self, *args):
        print('on_active')

    def on_packet(self, *args):
        print('on_packet')
        print(args)


class FXCheckBox(CheckBox):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.bind(active=self.on_packet)

    def on_state(self, *args):
        print('on_state')

    def on_packet(self, *args):
        print('on_packet')
        print(args)


grid = GridLayout(cols=1)
sw = FXSwitch()
sw.bind(active=sw.on_packet)

grid.add_widget(sw)
grid.add_widget(FXSwitch())
grid.add_widget(FXCheckBox())
runTouchApp(grid)
```